# Prestashop Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226]

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I get an ERROR 500 when trying to access the BackOffice of my prestahsop, I can only enter with Debug mode on.

My hosting provider told me I should close connections on the script, but I don't know what to insert or modify to which script.

[PrestaShopException]
Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'u488328531_pcFsK' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 15)
at line 127 in file classes/db/DbPDO.php

```
122.     public function connect()
123.     {
124.         try {
125.             $this->link = $this->getPDO($this->server, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database, 5);
126.         } catch (PDOException $e) {
127.             throw new PrestaShopException('Link to database cannot be established: ' . $e->getMessage());
128.         }
129. 
130.         $this->link->exec('SET SESSION sql_mode = \'\'');
131. 
132.         return $this->link;


DbPDOCore->connect - [line 330 - classes/db/Db.php]
DbCore->__construct - [line 241 - classes/db/Db.php] - [4 Arguments]
DbCore::getInstance - [line 47 - config/alias.php]
pSQL - [line 340 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
ShopCore::initialize - [line 119 - config/config.inc.php]
require - [line 40 - admin/index.php] - [1 Arguments]enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here
5 years of work down the drain with prestashop

**[PrestaShopException]**

Link to database cannot be established: **SQLSTATE[08004] [1040]** Too many connections
at **line 127** in file **classes/db/DbPDO.php**

```
     public function connect()
     {
         try {
             $this->link = $this->getPDO($this->server, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database, 5);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
127.      throw new PrestaShopException('Link to database cannot be established: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }
 
        $this->link->exec('SET SESSION sql_mode = \'\'');

        return $this->link;


    DbPDOCore->connect - [line 330 - classes/db/Db.php]

    DbCore->__construct - [line 241 - classes/db/Db.php] - [4 Arguments]
    DbCore::getInstance - [line 47 - config/alias.php]
    pSQL - [line 340 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
    ShopCore::initialize - [line 119 - config/config.inc.php]
    require - [line 27 - index.php] - [1 Arguments]
```

Comment: Hi, improve your answer to a [good edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)